# clear specific query in the QueryRegion

Tags: hibernate, caching, second-level-cache, hazelcast

How can I clear a specific query in some query region that I created, and not all of the query region.

I'm using Hibernate and Hazelcast as second level cache.

Comment: I'm executing the following query : "select * from accounts o where o.userId=1", gets 2 results and put that into query region named "userAccountsRegion". Then I'm executing another query "select * from accounts o where o.userId=2", gets 3 results and put that into the same query region. Now I want to delete the first query from the cache. How can i do this ?